# Inicio inmediato de múltiples hilos en Java

Tags: java, archivo, hilos

He creado un código que permita a base de múltiples hilos (multiple threading) crear varios archivos paralelamente.

Acá el código base que utilizo en el proyecto:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            FileCreator c = new FileCreator();
            for(int i=0;i<5000;i++){
                String name=String.valueOf(i+1);
                Thread t=new Thread(c);
                t.setName(name);
                t.start();
            }
            System.out.println("FINAL");
        }catch (Throwable ex){
            System.out.println("Error: "+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static class FileCreator implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run(){
            String nombre=Thread.currentThread().getName();
            try{
                System.out.println("INICIANDO "+nombre);
                String s=System.getProperty("file.separator"),path=System.getProperty("user.dir")+s+"res",file=path+s+nombre+".txt";
                File dir=new File(path);
                if(!dir.exists()) dir.mkdirs();
                StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
                for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){
                    sb.append(i).append("\r\n");
                }
                try(BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file),"ISO-8859-1"))){
                    bw.write(sb.toString());
                    bw.flush();
                    sb.delete(0,sb.length());
                }
                r();
                if(new File(file).exists()){
                    System.out.println("Archivo "+nombre+" creado");
                }
            }catch (Throwable ex){
                System.out.println("Error: "+ex.getMessage());
            }finally{
                System.out.println("TERMINANDO "+nombre);
            }
        }

        public void r(){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }catch (InterruptedException ex){
                System.out.println("Error: "+ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
 }
```

Gracias al orden en que se imprimen los mensajes de "inicio" y "terminado", he notado que los procesos no se ejecutan mientras que estoy creando otros hilos, sino hasta que se hayan finalizado de crear todos los hilos. De igual manera reviso el directorio resultado y los archivos no se empiezan a generar hasta el momento que menciono.

Esto es un problema dado que el objetivo de este código es trabajar con información más pesada (no como la del ejemplo anterior) y en tiempo récord para agilizar los procesos.

Cuando realizo la generación de 10 mil archivos (diferentes de los del ejemplo) en un servidor de 16 GB de RAM y procesador de 64 bits de 8 nucleos y 3.0 GHz, el procesador se satura y al final el programa se congela antes de siquiera generar algunos archivos.

¿Hay una manera de hacer que los hilos se ejecuten paralelamente mientras se crean otros hilos? Y de igual manera limpie recursos del sistema para que no se sature.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Multithreading es muy útil en ciertas situaciones pero no es una varita mágica que te permita reducir arbitrariamente el tiempo de ejecución de una aplicación. Si tienes el disco duro saturado, no te hará que vaya más rápido, ni te apareceran *cores* en la CPU si éstos ya están al 100%.

Y la gestión de los *threads* lleva asociada sus propios costes; crear 5.000 (5.000!!!!) threads<sup>1</sup> y los cambios de contexto entre threads para irse ejecutando son un coste considerable para cualquier sistema. Prueba a crear 5.000 threads que se limiten a no hacer nada, y dime cuánto tardan esos 5.000 threads en no hacer nada.

Los números de threads generalmente aconsejados son en general bastante menos y vinculados al número de cores disponibles<sup>2</sup>, y al tipo de tarea<sup>3</sup>. De hecho, y como al final la gente tenía que establecer sus propios sistemas de control para evitar crear demasiados *threads* y colapsar el sistema, el API de Java añadio los *ExecutorService* para que éste gestionara los *threads* (incluyendo número máximo) y la gente solo enviara tareas a los *executorService* para que este las asignara a un *thread*.

Respecto a la pregunta en sí, tan pronto a un *thread* le invocas el `start()`, aparece en el SO. Pero para ejecutarse tendrá que esperar a que el *scheduler* del SO le asigne un *core* libre (y para eso deberá haber un *core* libre, lo cual llevará su tiempo si hay miles de *threads* compitiendo por ellos). También será el *scheduler* el que decida si interrumpe el *thread* principal mientras está creando *threads* o no.

Con `setPriority` puedes cambiarle la prioridad al *thread* y el *dispatcher* lo tendrá en cuenta *según su propio algoritmo*, pero como se ha comentado más arriba eso no solucionará tu problema.

---

<sup>1</sup>Y no olvidemos que el SO y los otros programas del sistema tendrán sus propios *threads*.

<sup>2</sup>Si alguien me dijera 2x-3x el número de cores me empezaría a parecer excesivo y algo a revisar con cuidado. Así que imagina. En aplicaciones serias, el número de *threads* se deja como algo configurable para que la gente de Sistemas los pueda ajustar según las características del HW y de la tarea, según experimentación.

<sup>3</sup>Las tareas de I/O es más probable que se bloqueen, así que dejan más tiempo libre para la ejecución de otros *threads*; las de cálculo intensivo no suelen beneficiarse de crear múltiples *threads* porque no se quedan a la espera de otros eventos.

Comment: Comprendo la teoría, pero cuando hago pruebas de comparación, en el caso basado en el ejemplo que he mostrado, en un mono hilo 5000 archivos se tarda una eternidad, pero si aplico el multi hilo, los genera en 25 segundos.
El problema viene cuando son archivos complejos.
Pero basándome en lo que me has dicho, sería bueno trabajarlo en paquetes pequeños.
Pero me hubiera gustado un modo que supiera aprovechar los recursos del sistema...